# Brushed DC motor with incremental encoder-- How do I use it?

Tags: microcontroller, dc-motor, motor-controller, encoder

I have come across large brushed DC motor, a Dunkermotoren GR 53X30 with an incremental encoder attached. Here are the spec sheets for the motor and the encoder:

http://www.dunkermotor.com/data/technical_data/motors/pdf/121005_GR53x30.pdf#page=1
http://www.dunkermotor.com/data/technical_data/servocomponents/pdf/Inkrementalgeber_RE.pdf#page=1

I'm fairly new to the electronics tinkering world and have a few questions about controlling it. I have a few microcontrollers lying around, a TI MSP430 and an Arduino UNO, and a 30 V, 5 A variable powersupply. I'd like to play around with the motor a bit, and possibly use it for a project I'm working on. My questions:

- What purposes does the encoder serve?
- What kinds of control is this motor capable of (i.e. braking, reverse, etc)?
- Is my power supply able to provide enough amps to use it properly or is there the possibility of damaging it?

Comment: Do you know from the data sheet which motor version you have and are you aware that tinkering requires special qualifications?

Comment: @Andyaka - Yes tinkering without an amafor could be very serious. The encoder is used to measure how far the motor is turning - in this case its an incremental one (you count pulses). Its a DC motor forward/reverse - change the direction of current. Braking usually not immediate. From the spec sheet it shows 4.5 amps for 12V - fairly hefty. You'll need to have some sort if interface between the motor and your Arduino (e.g. relay / transistor/ mosfet ) to control it.

Comment: @JImDearden hmmm "amafor" I won't ask the obvious LOL

Comment: How do I figure out what signals to use to , for example, brake the motor? Is it able to accept regular PWM to control motor speed, even with the encoder?

Comment: @Andyaka - you nailed it.  As for braking you could use a short circuit across the motor (remove the power to it first!!!!!). The moving motor acts as a generator and shorting it out will make it act as magnetic break. N.B. Turn the motor power off first.